# Why use Long.valueOf(...) rather than a long literal?

Tags: java

Recently I stumbled over code where people write stuff like

```
Long myLong = Long.valueOf(42);

// instead of

Long myLong = 42L;
```

I have no clue why one would do this, except for personal taste regarding readability.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Probably because they aren't aware of the `42L` syntax.

Comment: Maybe the author did not know about long literals.

Comment: when you use 'Long' what happens is you go by the instincts of 'Objects' so tend to use methods , and plus same as what @MagnusGrindalBakken said , I my self never tried it :P

Comment: Where I work we use FindBugs to help clean up old code, and one thing it flags is `new Integer()`, but its suggestion is to use `valueOf()` instead. So I see a lot of people use `valueOf()`...

Comment: @DHall I actually think you've got it. We also use FindBugs, PMD and Checkstyle. You know, a fool with a tool...

Comment: @DHall : PMD also invite you to use Long.valueOf : cf http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.0.5/rules/java/migrating.html (part LongInstantiation)

Comment: @chburd We actually also use PMD. And CheckStyle - I'll have to investigate on this one, too, and tell my colleagues to ignore their semi-smart solutions...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

with direct assignment you are required to cast if assigning `int` to `Long` (`int` to primitive `long` is implicit) and they get `autoboxed` automatically using `Long.valueOf`

```
    Long myLong1 = Long.valueOf(42);
    Long myLong2 = Long.valueOf(42L);
    Long myLong3 = 42L;
    Long myLong4 = (long) 42;
```

otherwise they are all same See *bytecode* output from `javap`

```
  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: ldc2_w        #16                 // long 42l
       3: invokestatic  #18                 // Method java/lang/Long.valueOf:(J)Ljava/lang/Long;
       6: astore_1      
       7: ldc2_w        #16                 // long 42l
      10: invokestatic  #18                 // Method java/lang/Long.valueOf:(J)Ljava/lang/Long;
      13: astore_2      
      14: ldc2_w        #16                 // long 42l
      17: invokestatic  #18                 // Method java/lang/Long.valueOf:(J)Ljava/lang/Long;
      20: astore_3      
      21: ldc2_w        #16                 // long 42l
      24: invokestatic  #18                 // Method java/lang/Long.valueOf:(J)Ljava/lang/Long;
      27: astore        4
      29: return
```

However using `new Long(42L)` should be avoided if not absolutely necessary and one of above statement needs to be used in favor of this as `valueOf` methods normally cache a range of values (`FlyWeight Design Pattern`) by JVM internally

*Trivia: In case of integers & Oracle JVM the range can be controlled using `-XX:AutoBoxCacheMax=`*

Comment: @chrylis yes buy not auto boxing. try `Long myLong4 =  42;`

Answer (score 4):

The snippet

```
Long myLong = 42L;
```

is internally the same as

```
Long myLong = Long.valueOf(42);
```

The compiler will generate the same bytecode.

Answer (score 3):

I also think it's a reminder of java before java5, where there was no autoboxing, and where

```
Long l = 42L;
```

could not be compiled.

Comment: But before Java5, there was no valueOf(long) either :)

Comment: indeed : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#valueOf(long)

Answer (score 2):

They are equivalent, compiler will build the same bytecode for both

Comment: Are you sure about that?

Comment: @DavidWallace yes Please see `javap` output in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

[`valueOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#valueOf%28long%29) takes a primitive `long`. For literals, I'd agree that `42L` is better, but if you have an `int` or `long` variable, `Long.valueOf` is a good way to get a `Long`.  `valueOf` also uses a cache of values from -128 to 127, which gives it a slight performance edge over `new Long(long)` for common values.

Comment: You can also use the assignment with primitive long variables. It should still be the same (`Long myLong = myPrimitiveLong;`)

Comment: @Puce hm, good point. But it still could be useful when you want to call instance methods on `Long`, like `Long.valueOf(myPrimitive).compareTo(otherPrimitive)`; or for some other reason you want a `Long` without necessarily assigning it to a primitive.

Answer (score 1):

People who don't realize you can do it the other way?

I have to wonder if the compiler is smart enough to convert the Long.valueOf to the same bytecode, for constant calls.  Otherwise there would be a tiny performance hit (not significant, but you might notice it heavily-run, tight loops).

The valueOf version is useful for casting primitive values safely, handy if you're doing a bunch of casts between primitive types and don't want to (for example) cause problems doing:
 (int)longBiggerThanIntCanHandle

(You wouldn't care about doing (long)intValue, but if you're doing a bunch of conversions both ways, it's good to use valueOf as a convention, for safety.)